# Parallax Image Class in Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, parallax, visual-composer

I would like to add an Extra class name to certain images to make them parallax. I'm not trying to do this with a background- in my current situation, i'm working with an inner row, but think the effect would be great.

Soundcloud uses a similar effect in there app where just about all there images are parallax without full with, so it creates a kind of window effect.

I would need a line or two added to my child theme css file and also the extra class name to add to the visual composer image.

Thanks any advice, workarounds, or solutions will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed the concept of how parallax scrolling works.

> Parallax scrolling is a web site trend where the background content
>   (i.e. an image) is moved at a different speed than the foreground
>   content while scrolling.
>   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

You don't have to use an image as the background, as background-color is also a viable property that you could use.  Keith Clark has a nice tutorial on CSS-only parallax at https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

As to using WPBakery Page Builder (Formerly Visual Composer) to add classes to an inner row - there is a spot to add the class name at the bottom of the general tab when you create your inner row. [WPBakery Inner Row Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTOPI.png)